# Hadoop JobClient getJob method takes too long to execute

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I'm trying to fetch the currently running job from a `Hadoop 2.6.0` cluster using the *jobId*.

I have as input the jobId of the currently running Hadoop jobs. Using the RunningJob object, I want to fetch details about the Hadoop Job

I'm using Hadoop 2.x Java API.

For this I used the following code:

```
JobID jobID = JobID.forName(jobId);
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
JobClient client = new JobClient(new InetSocketAddress(ip,conf));
RunningJob job = client.getJob(jobId);
```

If the job is currently in `RUNNING` stage, the `getJob()` takes too long to execute.

I'm not able to understand why this is taking too much time to get the RunningJob object.

I have tried same in `Hadoop 1.1.2` version, but there I didn't face this issue. In this case, I used the Hadoop 1.x Java API.

Comment: You can move to new API with Hadoop 2.x version. Just use Job API as per below link : http://blog.puneethabm.in/wordcount-mapreduce-program-using-hadoop-new-api-2/

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to get information of the Hadoop Job which is running in a given cluster. I'm using Hadoop 2.x api for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue today. 
Hadoop's JobClient expects 3 must parameters to track your job from yarn.

**1. yarn.resourcemanager.address**

**2. mapreduce.jobhistory.address**

**3. mapreduce.framework.name**

and it should be called in following way to create jobClient

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address",jobTrackerIp);
conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.address",jobHistoryIp);
JobClient client = new JobClient(conf);
```

Once it is created in this way jobClient is ready for use. They have suppressed some of the errors in backend and used retry logic. That's why we are not able to see any error in our code.